# How do I compare enums in a Play Framework 2 form?

Tags: forms, scala, enums, playframework, playframework-2.0

How do I compare an enum in a Play Framework 2 form to an enum value?  This statement fails even when they are equal.

```
@if(myForm("sectionType").value == SectionType.MAIN_CONTACT_INFO) {
}
```

Comment: What type of `myForm("sectionType").value`?

Comment: `myForm("sectionType")` is type `play.api.data.Field`.  It says  `myForm("sectionType").value is type `Option[String]`.

Comment: I also tried  @if(myForm("sectionType").value.toString == SectionType.MAIN_CONTACT_INFO.toString).  This fails, even though both toString methods return "MAIN_CONTACT_INFO".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said that `myForm("sectionType").value` is an `Option[String]`, so you can't use directly `toString`, because `Some("hello").toString` return "Some(hello)".

I suggest trying with this syntax:

```scala
myForm("sectionType").value.get == SectionType.MAIN_CONTACT_INFO.toString
// or .getOrElse("") to avoid errors
```

And don't forget to import `SectionType` if necessary (ie. if this class is not in the models package)

Comment: That syntax works.  The import wasn't needed for some reason.